# array not updating value when sending in response

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, object, scope

I am trying to send back "projets" array inside an expressJs route after getting each item images, but when sending back the response with updated array the new added fields doesn't seem to be there.

Ps: when I console log the added item it displays with the correct updated item.

```
var projets = await Annonce.find(
  { type_annonce: { $ne: "bien" }, deleted_at: { $eq: null } },
  null,
  { limit: 10, sort: { refreshed_at: -1 } }
);

for (let index = 0; index < projets.length; index++) {
  var images = await Image.find({ BienID: projets[index]._id });
  if (!images || images.length == 0) console.log("No images");
  else {
    projets[index].images = images;
  }
}

console.log(projets[1].images);
response.json({ annonces: projets });
```

Comment: Are you saying the JSON response contains only the `Annonce.find` result but not the added `.images`?

Comment: tips: try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(projets));` may be some of your projects doesn't have any images.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, and none of them have that images field already, am creating it in the function.

Comment: If you do `console.log(projets);` before `response.json(...);` do you see the images?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I fixed the issue by creating a new object and putting everything I need to return inside.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that "Annonce.find()" returns an immutable object, I just separated its results to get what the desired structure.